# Magento 2.4.2 Element 'css', attribute 'onload': The attribute 'onload' is not allowed

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Magento 2.4.2 Element 'css', attribute 'onload': The attribute 'onload' is not allowed.
Please help me figure out this error
thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="
 urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<head>
    <css src="Magento_Theme::css/theme/style.css" media="all" order="180" rel="preload" as="style" />
    <css src="Magento_Theme::css/theme/media.css" media="all" order="182" rel="preload" as="style" />
    <css rel="preload" src="Magento_Theme::css/trustpilot/trustpilot-widget.css" as="style"  media="all" />
    <css rel="preload" src="Magento_Theme::css/theme/google-review.css" as="style" media="all" />
    <css src="css/styles-m.css" rel="preload" as="style" />
    <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" rel="preload" as="style" />
    <css src="Magento_Theme::css/font-awesome.min.css" media="all"/>
    <remove src="mage/calendar.css"/>

    <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js" />
    <!-- <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"/> -->
    <script src="Magento_Theme::js/lazyload/lazy.js" />     
    <script src="Magento_Theme::js/theme-general.js"/>
    
    <link rel="preload" src="fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" order="100"/>
    <link rel="preload" src="fonts/opensans/regular/opensans-400.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" order="110"/>
    <link rel="preload" src="fonts/opensans/semibold/opensans-600.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" order="120"/>
    <link rel="preload" src="fonts/opensans/bold/opensans-700.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" order="130"/>
</head>
</page>
```

Comment: add your xml file code here.

Comment: @RohanHapani question is updated

Comment: There are no any on load attribute exist in this file. It seems like error return from other.

Comment: Is it solved..?

Comment: No not found in any files. but still it's error

Comment: I added in my xml. It's working fine. So, it's return from other files. grep onload attribute in whole xml of customize folders.